# kdb+/q: Apply iterative procedure with updated variable to a column

Tags: kdb

Consider the following procedure `f:{[x] ..}` with starting value `a:0`:

1. Do something with `x` and `a`. The output is saved as the new version of `a`, and the output is returned by the function
2. For the next input `x`, redo the procedure but now with the new `a`.

For a single value `x`, this procedure is easily constructed. For example:

```
a:0;
f:{[x] a::a+x; :a}       / A simple example (actual function more complicated)
```

However, how do I make such a function such that it also works when applied on a table column?

I am clueless how to incorporate this step for 'intermediate saving of a variable' in a function that can be applied on a column at once. Is there a special technique for this? E.g. when I use a table column in the example above, it will simply calculate `a+x` with `a:0` for all rows, opposed to also updating `a` at each iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use global vars for this - can use `scan` instead - see [here](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#scan).

Example --

Generate a table -

```
q)t:0N!([] time:5?.z.p; sym:5?`3; price:5?100f; size:5?10000)
    time                          sym price    size
    -----------------------------------------------
    2002.04.04D18:06:07.889113280 cmj 29.07093 3994
    2007.05.21D04:26:13.021438816 llm 7.347808 496
    2010.10.30D10:15:14.157553088 obp 31.59526 1728
    2005.11.01D21:15:54.022395584 dhc 34.10485 5486
    2005.03.06D21:05:07.403334368 mho 86.17972 2318
```

Example with a simple accumilator - note, the function has access to the other args if needed (see next example):

```
q)update someCol:{[a;x;y;z] (a+1)}\[0;time;price;size] from t
    time                          sym price    size someCol
    -------------------------------------------------------
    2002.04.04D18:06:07.889113280 cmj 29.07093 3994 1
    2007.05.21D04:26:13.021438816 llm 7.347808 496  2
    2010.10.30D10:15:14.157553088 obp 31.59526 1728 3
    2005.11.01D21:15:54.022395584 dhc 34.10485 5486 4
    2005.03.06D21:05:07.403334368 mho 86.17972 2318 5
```

Say you wanted to get cumilative size:

```
q)update cuSize:{[a;x;y;z] (a+z)}\[0;time;price;size] from t
    time                          sym price    size cuSize
    ------------------------------------------------------
    2002.04.04D18:06:07.889113280 cmj 29.07093 3994 3994
    2007.05.21D04:26:13.021438816 llm 7.347808 496  4490
    2010.10.30D10:15:14.157553088 obp 31.59526 1728 6218
    2005.11.01D21:15:54.022395584 dhc 34.10485 5486 11704
    2005.03.06D21:05:07.403334368 mho 86.17972 2318 14022
```

If you wanted more than one var passed through the scan, can pack more values into the first var, by giving it a more complex structure:

```
q)update cuPriceAndSize:{[a;x;y;z] (a[0]+y;a[1]+z)}\[0 0;time;price;size] from t
    time                          sym price    size cuPriceAndSize
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    2002.04.04D18:06:07.889113280 cmj 29.07093 3994 29.07093 3994
    2007.05.21D04:26:13.021438816 llm 7.347808 496  36.41874 4490
    2010.10.30D10:15:14.157553088 obp 31.59526 1728 68.014   6218
    2005.11.01D21:15:54.022395584 dhc 34.10485 5486 102.1188 11704
    2005.03.06D21:05:07.403334368 mho 86.17972 2318 188.2986 14022
```

Answer (score 1):

@MdSalih solution is correct, I am just explaining here what could be the possible reason with global variable in your case and solution for that.

```
q) t:([]id: 1 2)
q)a:1
```

I think you might have been using it like this:

```
q) select k:{x:x+a;a::a+1;:x} id from t
```

output:

```
k 
--
1
2
```

And `a` value is 2 which means function executed only once. Reason is we passed full `id` column list to function and (`+`) is atomic which means it operates on full list at once. In following ex. 2 will get added to all items in list.

```
q) 2 + (1;3;5)
```

Correct way to use it is 'each':

```
q)select k:{x:x+a;a::a+1;:x} each id from t
```

output:

```
k 
--
2
3
```